# Attempting to overfit simple neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to overfit a network over simple data. The data I'm working with is the MNIST image dataset, 60000 training images of size 784 pixels.

What I want to do is a form of phase retrieval. I took the MNIST dataset and performed 2 variable fourier transform on it. This transformed the 60000 by 784 real matrix into a 60000 by 784 complex matrix.

Finally then, I took the absolute value of each number, and put it in a new 60000 by 784 real matrix, called amplitudes, and i also took the angle (or phase) of each number and put it in a 60000 by 784 matrix of real numbers called phases.

The goal is to predict the phases given the amplitudes.

this is the extremely simple code

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

def normalize_angles(phases):
    phases = phases + np.pi
    phases /= (2 * np.pi)
    return phases

def build_fourier_mnist():
    mnist = np.load("train_features.npy") #MNIST as is.
    fourier_mnist = np.zeros(mnist.shape, dtype=np.complex)
    for i in range(mnist.shape[0]):
        current_image = np.reshape(mnist[i, :], (28, 28)) #Turn to matrix so we can perform 2d fft
        fourier_current_image = np.fft.fft2(current_image) #perform 2d fft
        fourier_mnist[i, :] = np.reshape(fourier_current_image,(1, 784)) #flatten and save to new matrix
    return fourier_mnist

fourier_mnist = build_fourier_mnist()
amplitudes = np.abs(fourier_mnist)
phases = normalize_angles(np.angle(fourier_mnist))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(784, input_dim=amplitudes.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(784, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(784, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(784, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(phases.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
#Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
#Fit the model
model.fit(amplitudes, phases, epochs=400, batch_size=100)
model.save("phase_retriever2.h5")
```

It does "work" in the sense that it gives a pretty ok result, but I'm trying to massively overfit it. The best training error I got was around 0.083. Can you get any better? How can I improve this?

Comment: If you don't mind asking what can be the applications of this?

Comment: The applications of phase retrieval are endless really. This is a very minor example of that. Phase retrieval means given the amplitude of a complex number, find the angle.

Comment: On this page [Phase retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_retrieval). It mentions about `Error reduction algorithm`. So you are trying to create a `ML` based algorithm for this right? Awesome

Comment: I'm trying but I seem to hit the 0.083 wall :)

Comment: Why don't you increase the `layers` and create a newer dataset with images with little bit `erosion` or `dilution` or `rotation` and increase the `batch` size?

Comment: Here are some guidance on Neural Net training by Karpathy : https://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/ . It could be useful.